# cant use Friend function declare in a class

Tags: c++, class

i have a problem , I have a class who I want to work , It's Log class to writ in .txt file the informations i need to debug / follow the process.

However I have difficulties with the "SupSrvLogInfo" method which i cant make work if you can please help me. I pretty sure it's juste a question of member access or something like that...

here is the class

```
class FileLogger {

        public:



            enum e_logType { SupError , SupEvtInfo , SupWarn , SupStatPer , SupStatEvt , SupEvtDbg };



            FileLogger (const char *version_, const char *fname = "log.txt")
                    :   numWarnings (0U),
                        numErrors (0U)
            {

                myFile.open (fname);

                //  premieres lignes
                if (myFile.is_open()) {
                    myFile << "version " << version_ << std::endl;
                    myFile << "Log file created" << std::endl << std::endl;
                    myFile << currentDateTime() << std::endl ;
                }

            }




            ~FileLogger () {

                if (myFile.is_open()) {
                    myFile << std::endl << std::endl;

                    // A la fin calcul nombre error et warnings
                    myFile << numWarnings << " warnings" << std::endl;
                    myFile << numErrors << " errors" << std::endl;
                    myFile << currentDateTime() << std::endl ;

                    myFile.close();
                } // if

            }


            friend FileLogger &operator << (FileLogger &logger, const char *text) {

                logger.myFile << text << std::endl;
                return logger;

            }


        friend void SupSrvLogInfo(FileLogger &logger,const e_logType l_type){
                logger.myFile << currentDateTime();
                switch (l_type) {
                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupError:
                        logger.myFile << "[ERROR]: ";
                        ++logger.numErrors;
                        break;

                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupWarn:
                        logger.myFile << "[WARNING]: ";
                        ++logger.numWarnings;
                        break;

                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupEvtInfo:
                        logger.myFile << "[INFO]: ";
                        break;

                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupStatPer:
                        logger.myFile << "[PERIODIC_STAT]: ";
                        break;
                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupStatEvt:
                        logger.myFile << "[SPECIFIC_STAT]: ";
                        break;
                    case FileLogger::e_logType::SupEvtDbg:
                        logger.myFile << "[DEBUG_INFO]: ";

                        break;
                } //




            }



        private:

            std::ofstream           myFile;
            unsigned int            numWarnings;
            unsigned int            numErrors;

    }; // class end
```

And then I declare my object to have my text file. But cant get the method work , Code block dont even see my function saying wasnt declare in this scope, i suppose its because of the friend ?  :

```
FileLogger SupSrvFile("V0", "///home/etcap/Documents/code/SupSrv/SupSrV.txt" ); // Creating my object working fine 

// Trying now to have for example an Error message in my log file 
SupSrvFile.supSrvLogInfo(SupSrvfile, SupError) // NOT WORKING AT ALL 
supSrvLogInfo(SupSrvfile, SupError) // NOT WORKING AT ALL 
supSrvLogInfo(SupSrvfile.SupError) // NOT WORKING AT ALL
```

Comment: C++ is case sensitive see `SupSrvLogInfo` and `supSrvLogInfo`. Flagged as a typo.

Comment: Also, when you declare a `friend` function inside a class, it's not a member of the class. And since you pass a class instance as the first argument, are you sure it makes sense to have it as a non-member friend function instead of a proper member function?

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for your advice however it didn't change my problem even with good typo :(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was affraid that i might not change the member since i used "myfile" wich is private

Comment: Furthermore, enumerations defined in classes are scoped in those classes, and you need to prefix them, as in `FileLogger::SupError`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you !!!! When I do SupSrvFile.supSrvLogInfo(SupSrvFile,FileLogger::Su^pError) its working but i cant add "<<"Something" after that to add text because i overload my operator << ..

Comment: First of all it's *still* not a member function (unless you changed that, and then you don't need to pass the object itself as an argument); And secondly the function returns `void`, i.e. nothing.

Comment: I did change that my bad , thank you for your help , it was really benefict to me